# WPF C# Setting Font Family of Text Block

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I am looking for the correct sytanx for setting a custom defined font in the xaml.cs file. In the .xaml file, I can successfully do this:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Resources/#Charlemagne Std" FontSize="22" ... />
```

However, I cannot seem to get the same thing to work in the .xaml.cs file. I have tried something to this effect:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.FontFamily = new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/"), "#Charlemagne Std");
```

The font is in the Resources folder of my project folder. The name of the font is Charlemagne Std, and the name of the font file is chalemagnestd-regular.otf.

There were no compile errors, but the font showing does not seem to be correct.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the font is in a subfolder of the project folder, you'll need to include that folder path when constructing the FontFamily object. Use:

```
new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/"), "./Resources/#Charlemagne Std");
```

For more information, see [Packaging Fonts with Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx) on MSDN.